# textbox backgroundcolor change by validator

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, validation

I have several required textboxes with RequiredFieldValidators on my webpage, WITH a validationgroup for a summary and several classes around it (div's, on the textbox itself too)

I found a lot of examples how to it, but none of them has a validationgroup. If I add the validationgroup the backgroundcolor won't change, if I remove the Validationgroup the backgroundcolor will be changed but the summary does not show any errormessages.

I tried with jQuery and C# still no result, does someone has an working example or link??
I prefer a clientside sollution for optimazation reasons.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us your code, at least your HTML and preferably as JSFiddle?

Comment: you could make a css style that is .class .error and with jquery add .error when validated and remove it when corrected i do not use .net so this is just a sugestion, in my place i would validate the form using jquery validation plugin. if you post your code it could be eassier

Answer (score 2):

http://savotdane.blogspot.com/2008/10/hightlight-or-change-background-color.html
hope this link will help you.
or you can call a function on button client click which have

```
var val = Page_ClientValidate();
if (!val) {
    var i = 0;
    for (; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        if (!Page_Validators[i].isvalid) {
            $("#" + Page_Validators[i].controltovalidate)
             .css("background-color", "red");
        }
    }
}            
return val;
```